# Which COVID entry rules apply when transitioning in the Schengen area?

Tags: schengen, transit, covid-19

I am supposed to fly soon from outside the EU to spain, connecting through Germany. I am fully vaccinated and boosted, so this question is mostly of theoretical interest.

Entering spain from non-EU countries still requires a vaccination certificate (or a negative test/recovery certificate):
https://www.sanidad.gob.es/en/profesionales/saludPublica/ccayes/alertasActual/nCov/spth.htm

However, entering spain from EU countries does not require any COVID documentation (same link), and neither does entering Germany from (almost) anywhere in the world:
https://www.auswaertiges-amt.de/en/coronavirus/2317268

So, does it mean that non-vaccinated, non-tested tourists can bypass Spanish entry rules by simply connecting via Germany? It sounds very strange, but I don't see any way to prevent this.

Comment: Bypassing Covid entry rules was a thing even back in 2020 with the Croatia loophole: https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/166755/is-portugal-open-for-travelers-from-turkey/166760#166760. And yes, it doesn’t make any sense.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the pandemic is now over.